# Using multiple jython PythonInterpreter objects with different PYTHONPATHs

Tags: java, jython

I had an insidious problem with imports failing, that we finally traced down to using multiple [`PythonInterpreter`](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html) objects that needed different `PYTHONPATH` settings. I had a constructor that looked like this:

```
public class Thingy
{
   final private PythonInterpreter pi;

   public Thingy(String pythonPath)
   {
      System.getProperties().setProperty("python.path", pythonPath);
      this.pi = new PythonInterpreter();
   }
   ...
}
```

and the problem is that two instances of it won't work correctly because they rely on system properties for `python.path` which are singletons. And oddly enough, it looks like the *first* one wins rather than the *last* one, which tells me that there's probably some singleton code in Jython that reads the `python.path` system property when the Jython library initializes.

Some test code to illustrate the problem:

```
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

public class SingletonTest {
    final private PythonInterpreter pi;
    final private String objid;

    public SingletonTest(String id, String pythonPath)
    {
        System.getProperties().setProperty("python.path", pythonPath);
        this.objid = id;
        this.pi = new PythonInterpreter();
    }
    public void exec(String code)
    {
        try
        {
            this.pi.exec(code);
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e)
        {
            System.err.printf("id=%s", this.objid);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SingletonTest dee = new SingletonTest("tweedledee", "c:/tmp/test1/tweedledee");
        dee.exec("import foo");

        SingletonTest dum = new SingletonTest("tweedledum", "c:/tmp/test1/tweedledum");
        dum.exec("import bar");
    }
}
```

c:/tmp/test1/tweedledee/foo.py:

```
print "Yay, foo loaded"
```

c:/tmp/test1/tweedledum/bar.py:

```
print "Yay, bar loaded"
```

and this program prints

```
Yay, foo loaded
id=tweedledumTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named bar
```

I fixed it by changing the constructor to set up `sys.path` within Jython itself:

```
public SingletonTest(String id, String pythonPath)
{
    this.objid = id;
    this.pi = new PythonInterpreter();
    this.pi.exec(String.format("import sys\nsys.path.append('%s')", 
            pythonPath.replace("\\","/")));
    // replace backslashes with fwd slashes so the Python interpreter
    // doesn't get tripped up (we could also escape them)
}
```

but that seems very hacky and subject to [Little Bobby Tables attacks](https://xkcd.com/327/) if `pythonPath` is something like `dummy')\ndo_something_evil()\n`. The Jython equivalent of an SQL prepared statement doesn't seem to exist, though.

*Is there a better way to setup the `PYTHONPATH` path for individual `PythonInterpreter` instances so that each instance can have a different `PYTHONPATH` setting?*

Comment: GACK!!! It looks like two instances of PythonInterpreter share the same `sys.path` object. :( BAD DESIGN.